# Dump heap in SBCL

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

My program execution was aborted with the following diagnostics:

```
Heap exhausted during garbage collection: 0 bytes available, 16 requested.
Gen  Boxed   Code    Raw  LgBox LgCode  LgRaw  Pin       Alloc     Waste        Trig      WP GCs Mem-age
 3   21843      1     47      0      0      0   59   716955392    368896     2000000   21891   0  1.0481
 4       0      0      0      0      0      0    0           0         0     2000000       0   0  0.0000
 5       0      0      0      0      0      0    0           0         0     2000000       0   0  0.0000
 6     491      2    223     55      0     10    0    24917312    674496     2000000     781   0  0.0000
 7   10080      0     15      0      0      0    0   330663696    129264     2000000   10095   0  0.0000
           Total bytes allocated    =    1072536400
           Dynamic-space-size bytes =    1073741824
GC control variables:
   *GC-INHIBIT* = true
   *GC-PENDING* = true
   *STOP-FOR-GC-PENDING* = false
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 88102(tid 0x7fff9e07c380):
Heap exhausted, game over.

Welcome to LDB, a low-level debugger for the Lisp runtime environment.
ldb>
```

Is there a way to find where all of the memory was consumed?
The program itself is here: https://github.com/hemml/gridgen2

Answer (score 1):

SBCL's `(room t)` will give you quite a bit more information if you can do it before you run out of heap.  I'm  unfamiliar with LDB and whether or not it can execute `room`.  However you could wrap a call to `(room t)` with something that redirects its output to file, and add the function to the `*after-gc-hooks*` list so you can see the (extremely verbose) growth patterns.